# htaccess to rewrite file in subfolder (2nd level) to folder (1st level)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting

Currently, I'm using the below htaccess code to load http://www.domain.com/folder/file.php from http://www.domain.com/file, removing the folder name "/folder/", and the file extension ".php", from the URL.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/folder%{REQUEST_URI}\.php -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/folder%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /folder/$1.php [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Now, I'm trying to do almost the same, but with a file that is stored in a subfolder.

So, in other words, I want to call http://www.domain.com/folder/subfolder/file.php from http://www.domain.com/subfolder/file

In this case, hiding the extension file is not a problem as the 2 last lines from the code above works globally, the issue is with the Rewriting which doesn't work simply by adding the 'subfolder' name. I thought this was going to work, but it wasn't:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/folder/subfolder%{REQUEST_URI}\.php -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/folder/subfolder%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /folder/subfolder/$1.php [L]
```

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace both of your rules with this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/folder/$1\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /folder/$1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.php [L]
```

Comment: Thank you anubhava. It didn't work, I got the 404 Not Found Error in both cases, using this code.

Comment: Is you .htaccess is not in DocumentRoot? Are there more rules in this .htaccess? Is `http://www.domain.com/file` giving 404 to you? What happens you use `http://www.domain.com/folder/file.php`?

Comment: Hi. Yes, the .htaccess is in the root domain folder. There are many more rules in this .htaccess, but I'm working with this one at the end of the file to avoid conflicts. The other rules in the .htaccess are simple RewriteRules to change URLs from domain.com/index.php?query=hello to  domain.com/hello.

When I use the the code you gave me.. and try http://www.domain.com/file, I got the 404 page. Everything else works normally.

Comment: Hi anubhava, sorry, my mistake. It works now. I was calling the /subfolder/ expecting this one loads the index.php by default, for example I was expecting http://www.domain.com/subfolder/ calls http://www.domain.com/subfolder/index.php. It didn't work in that way, but if I try http://www.domain.com/subfolder/index, it works. I'm just going to put another relative name to index.php. It works for me in that way too. Thanks buddy!

Comment: Actually `domain.com/subfolder` would also work if you add `DirectoryIndex index.php` line on top of this .htaccess

Comment: can we exclude some 3rd level folders in this rule?

Comment: Yes, that would be possible by tweaking regex patterns. I cannot provide rules code in comments as formatting gets lost. Feel free to post a new question, if needed.