# Mod_Rewrite from "TEST" folder to TEST.php

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I need to redirect this SEO-friendly URL:

> www.domain.com/language/page AND www.domain.com/language/page/

To:

> www.domain.com/language/page.php

I need to do this dynamically.
Language could be "en", or "it" or others..

Why is this not working? Got "error 404" (not found)

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])/(\w+)/?$ $1/$2.php [L]
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"?

Comment: @starkeen the url www.domain.com/language/page does not redirect/rewrite to page.php (got error 404)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [htaccess to rewrite file in subfolder (2nd level) to folder (1st level)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25563255/htaccess-to-rewrite-file-in-subfolder-2nd-level-to-folder-1st-level)